# overriding blueprint configuration per-controller in controller in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, model-view-controller, sails.js

I am new to sails framework.i am using sails 0.12 (on cmd v0.11.5).

i want to override blueprint actions only for particular controller. for that i have override configuration in my controller as following:

```
_config:{ defaultLimit : 3 , rest:true,actions:true,shortcuts:true },
```

but it doesn't work and it takes default configuration from blueprint.js.

so.how can i change them per controller?

Answer (score 1):

Sails has good functionality to override blueprint configuration.

please refer this link for override

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api#?disabling-blueprints-on-a-percontroller-basis

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api#?overriding-blueprints

Comment: I've already referred them but didn't get any help from them. i've written the same code

Comment: i have override rest routes check out https://github.com/ycpatel813/sails-override-blueprint/blob/master/config/blueprints.js

Comment: you are wrong .i've asked for per controller configuration.whatever you suggest is for whole application means common for all controllers.

Comment: I have set restful route false for all controller first then I have override catscontroller restful route. if I still understand wrong then need more description.

Comment: i did the same.but not working.only blueprints.js settings dominate all.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to create a Controller with the same name from your model. There, you can enable/disable the blueprint route for a specific model and override endpoints.

Eg:

```js
// if you have an User model at api/models/User.js
// the controller below must be at api/controllers/UserController.js

/**
 * UserController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side actions for handling incoming requests.
 * @help        :: See https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/actions
 */

module.exports = {

  _config: {
    rest: false
    // It's possible to disable some route, but you can't enable them if your
    // main configuration is set "true". (Sorry, I really don't know why of this)...
    // the main configuration file is located at: config/blueprints.js
  }

};
```

Also, they don't have a "defaultLimit" configuration. To override the endpoint, you just need to implement the method:

```js
// api/controller/UserController.js
/**
 * UserController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side actions for handling incoming requests.
 * @help        :: See https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/actions
 */

module.exports = {

  create: function (req, res) {
    console.log('custom create method called!');
    // res.ok(populatedRecord);
  },

  find: function (req, res) {
    console.log('custom find method called!');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to override a blueprint endpoint is creating a new route to that same endpoint:

```js
// config/routes.js
'POST /user': { action: 'create-user' },
```

This is often better because you can use actions.